# Python Remove dict items with duplicate field

Tags: python

I have the following list of dicts. I'd like to remove duplicates of the object field. What's the easiest way to to remove the item if that object has already appeared?

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 21, 42, 54, 634699),
  'object': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'subscription'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 21, 25, 51, 51554),
  'object': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'subscription'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 20, 59, 18, 211191),
  'object': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'subscription'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 18, 1, 37, 43482),
  'object': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'subscription'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 12, 18, 1, 24, 322306),
  'object': <TipList: mulligan - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 9, 23, 33, 17, 511657),
  'object': <TipList: mulligan - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 7, 16, 18, 51, 597775),
  'object': <TipList: mulligan - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'},
  'object': <TipList: mulligan - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 7, 10, 9, 12, 975944),
  'object': <TipList: mulligan - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'},
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 19, 20, 37, 26, 663267),
  'object': <TipList: a - Buenos Aires>,
  'subscription': <Subscription: Subscription object>,
  'type': 'tiplist'}]
```

Comment: We have no clue what `Subscription` looks like, nor what would constitute a duplicate `Subscription`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want the final result to look like.

Comment: Correction: You have the following _list_ of dicts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the `__hash__` method is correctly implemented for `Subscription` and `TipList` classes, I'd do something as follows:

```
seen = set()
new_l = []
for item in l:
    obj = item['object']
    if obj not in seen:
        seen.add(obj)
        new_l.append(item)
```

where `l` is the original list and `new_l` the list without the duplicates.